# Find list of Local Notification the app has already set

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

My app allows users to set a number of reminders in the future.  When the app lauches I want to know what reminders (notifications) have already been set.

Can I read back the notifications I have set or do I need to store in my app (e.g. Core Data or Plist)?

Comment: Is there a way to find upcoming notifications? (include that one that have repeat interval)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`UIApplication` has a property called [`scheduledLocalNotifications`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications) which returns an optional array containing elements of type `UILocalNotification`.

```swift
UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications
```

Comment: Hey scott Berrevoests, Please help me out. I am not getting my alarm from second time but is is already in the pending alarm list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132879/ios-local-notification-not-firing-second-time-but-shows-in-getpendingnotificatio

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Which method gets execute when app is in background and receives UNUserNotification?

Comment: Just a note that `scheduledLocalNotifications` is deprecated

Comment: @MattLeFleur is there a new way of doing this? I have trouble finding one.

Comment: @HenningHall, I'd use Frizzo's answer for the best way of doing this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39034576/810167

Answer (score 37):

For Swift 3.0 and Swift 4.0

**don't forget to do `import UserNotifications`**

> *This is working for **iOS10+** and **watchOS3+** since the class **UNUserNotificationCenter** is not available for older versions ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter))*

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
        print("Count: \(notifications.count)")
        for item in notifications {
          print(item.content)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method gets execute when app is in background and receives UNUserNotification?

Answer (score 22):

Scott is correct.

`UIApplication`'s property [scheduledLocalNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications)

Here's the code:

```
NSMutableArray *notifications = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[notifications addObject:notification];
app.scheduledLocalNotifications = notifications;
//Equivalent: [app setScheduledLocalNotifications:notifications];
```

---

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
    NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"]];
    if ([uid isEqualToString:uidtodelete])
    {
        //Cancelling local notification
        [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
        break;
    }
}
```

---

```
NSArray *arrayOfLocalNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] ;

for (UILocalNotification *localNotification in arrayOfLocalNotifications) {

    if ([localNotification.alertBody isEqualToString:savedTitle]) {
        NSLog(@"the notification this is canceld is %@", localNotification.alertBody);

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification] ; // delete the notification from the system

    }

}
```

---

For more info, check out this: [scheduledLocalNotifications example UIApplication ios](http://samplecodebank.blogspot.com/2013/05/scheduledlocalnotifications-example.html)

Comment: Thanks this also help with my next question regarding storing an ID for each notification - all done now...

Comment: This is a strange sample code. The OP is asking for listing the local notifications and you are showing an example how to cancel local notifications

Answer (score 6):

@Scott Berrevoets gave the correct answer. To actually list them, it is simple to enumerate the objects in the array:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UILocalNotification *notification, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Notification %lu: %@",(unsigned long)idx, notification);
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.0.2:

```
UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications
```

Answer (score 3):

In `iOS 10`, using the new `UserNotifications` framework:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { (notificationRequests) in

        print("Requests: \(notificationRequest)")
}
```

Comment: Which method gets execute when app is in background and receives UNUserNotification?

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { (requests) in

    for request in requests {

        if request.identifier == "IDENTIFIER YOU'RE CHECKING IF EXISTS" {

            //Notification already exists. Do stuff.

        } else if request === requests.last {

            //All requests have already been checked and notification with identifier wasn't found. Do stuff.

        }
    }
})
```

I used this to fix a bug where the same weekly notification was already set and being set again when the app would open, so it would keep resetting the timer to appear, which means it never did appear.

Comment: If I use this at the beginning to check if there are any notifications at all, it doesn't go through the loop at all.

Comment: Which method gets execute when app is in background and receives UNUserNotification?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, to see all your currently scheduled local notifications printed in the console:

```
print(UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications)
```