# UILocal notification

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to schedule local notification in my game.
First notification will come two hours after game play has ended.
After that another one come in the next 24 hours if still no gameplay. If gameplay resets to after 2 hours, then every 24 hrs until they enter game. 
I would be very thankful to you if you can help me.
Here is my code:

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notif.alertBody =  [self.notifyArray objectAtIndex:index];

NSTimeInterval sec = 7200;
notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:sec];
notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
NSLog(@"notif : %u",notif.repeatInterval);
notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];

//notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:20];
 //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Comment: Then what is wrong, tell us your problem. That is you are sending and notifications are not sending, you have problem with dates ?

Nobody will run your code and wait for 2 or 24 hours to check whether notification occurs or not.

What exactly issue you are facing ?

Comment: Local notification is not fired exactly with the same time. It fired every 10 second and fired 4-5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug first by checking the scheduled notifications list. You can see this thread for details [iOS find list of Local Notification the app has already set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531332/ios-find-list-of-local-notification-the-app-has-already-set)

Answer (score 0):

First give an 'identifier' to your local notification. Then and when app goes to background, use that identifier to identify notification from scheduled notifications of your application. And reschedule it after 2 hours , with repeat interval of day.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
   if ( oneEvent.identifier = yourNotificationIdentifier){
//Reschedule oneEvent.
}
}
```