# On iOS, how can my app get the notification data that it received while the phone was in the background?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way in AppDelegate to get a queue of all the notification data? (Once the user opens the app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per apple documentation:

When a remote notification arrives, the system calls the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method. Notifications usually signal the availability of new information. In your app delegate method, you might begin downloading new data from a server so that you can update your app’s data structures. You might also use the notification to update your user interface.

You have to enable `remote notification background mode`, only then you will get a callback to the above mentioned method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `app delegate`:

```
         - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
      fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

For `UILocalNotification`, you can get received notifications by calling following function in your `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    // Application was in the background when notification was delivered.
    } 
}
```

If you want to find the list of local Notifications, that app has already set, check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531332/find-list-of-local-notification-the-app-has-already-set).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for launchOptions Dictionary, for received Notification, when App resumes on tapping a notification,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
  NSLog(@"Launch Options:%@",launchOptions);

  return YES;
}
```